# Solving two unknown chord lengths of a circle using radius and a right triangle with lengths of its sides

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, circles

I'm trying to solve the length of x and y. The known info is the length of the right triangle sides which are 200 and 300, and the radius of the circle which is 1000.

[Image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNd6i.png)

This is what I have gotten so far:
First I calculated the hypotenuse using the Pythagorean theorem. With the length of the hypotenuse, using
$c=2R\sin\frac{θ}{2}$ formula I got the angle of θ.
$$R=1000$$
$$C=100\sqrt{13}$$
$$θ=2\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{C}{2\cdot R}\right)$$
$$θ=2\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{100\sqrt{13}}{2\cdot1000}\right)=20.771...^\circ$$

[My progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBzT4.png)

But after this, I'm out of ideas and not sure how to continue from here.

Comment: Hint: [Intersecting Chords Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersecting_chords_theorem#:~:text=The%20intersecting%20chords%20theorem%20or,on%20each%20chord%20are%20equal.)

Comment: Complete the right triangle with legs $y$ and $300$. The angle opposite to side with length $300$ is $\dfrac{\theta}{2}$. Now you can finish it off with simple trigonometry.

Comment: Thanks for the help @SathvikAcharya!

Comment: You're welcome :)